# Can I change margin in AnimatedContainer?

Tags: flutter, dart, animatedcontainer

I'm building a list using **ListWheelScrollView** and I would like to change **margin** value of container below the centre one. I'm also using **AnimatedContainer**.

```
 margin: const EdgeInsets.only( left: x == selected ? 13 : 10),
```

This code gives me error : **Error: Not a constant expression. left: x == selected ? 13 : 10),**
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: just remove const before EdgeInsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a very simple way to avoid this problem. You should remove the `const` keyword. The `const` keyword in Dart indicates that a value will not be changed after compiling. This will be violated when `x == selected` returns true for example.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Didn't expect such a simple solution.